# How to show that $x^2 \equiv 10 \bmod {101}$ does or does not have a solution

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I know that this is solvable using index arithmetic, but that would take forever to generate the index table. How do I show that this does or does not have a solution without trying to solve it?

Comment: No, it does not. $101 \equiv 1 \pmod 5,$ but $101 \equiv 5 \pmod 8.$

Comment: It has no solution. This might help: http://www.numbertheory.org/php/squareroot.html

Comment: Are you sure you wrote it down correctly?

Comment: I guess the question was more of how to show that this does or does not have a solution.

Answer (score 5):

Ah, so I was looking at this the wrong way. This is a quadratic residue problem and we can use legendre symbols to solve this problem. Namely we do (10/101) = (2/101)(5/101).By following the legendre properties we end up with (10/101) = -1 which means that this is not a quadratic residue and thus has no solution.

Comment: Which properties of the Legendre symbol are you using?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\,\ {\rm mod}\ 101\!:\,\ \color{#c00}{x^2\equiv 10}\:\Rightarrow\, 1\! \overset{\rm Fermat}\equiv\! (\color{#c00}{x^2})^{50}\equiv \color{#c00}{10}^{50}\equiv (10^2)^{25}\equiv (-1)^{25}\equiv -1\,\Rightarrow\!\Leftarrow$

**Remark** $\ $ i.e. $\,{\rm mod}\ p\!:\ x^4 \equiv -1 \,\Rightarrow\, {\rm ord}\, x = 8\mid p-1,\ $ for odd primes $\,p.$